# SFDX export related records for data upload to a scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx, custom-object, account, salesforcedx-cli

I have a relationship between `Account` and `MyCustomObject__c` where `Account.CustomField__c` is a lookup to `MyCustomObject__c`. When I try to export the field on the Account and related records using `sfdx`, after using the export command below the `Account.CustomField__c` is not populated but both `Account` and `MyCustomObject__c` records are exported into their respective files.

**Questions**

- How can I retrieve `Accounts` and `MyCustomObject__c` records using `sfdx` such that when uploaded both records will be created and `Account.CustomField__c` is populated?

**Current result**

- `Accounts` and `MyCustomObject__c` are exported but `Account.CustomField__c` is blank

**Expected Result**

- `Accounts` and `MyCustomObject__c` are exported and `Account.CustomField__c` is populated

**Query that I tried but didn't work as per the expected result**

```
Select Id, Name, CustomField__c,
(Select Id, Name From MyCustomObject__c)
From Account
```

**Observations**

- If the `CustomField__c` value (which is an Id) is not within the `Select Id, Name From MyCustomObject__c`, the sfdx command does not execute and return an error message

**sfdx command**

```
sfdx force:data:tree:export --query "Select Id, Name, CustomField__c, (Select Id, Name From MyCustomObject__r) From Account" --prefix accounts --outputdir my/output/dir --plan
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead -

```
sfdx force:data:tree:export --query "Select Id, Name, CustomField__c, (Select Id, Name From MyCustomObject__r) From Account" --prefix accounts --outputdir my/output/dir --plan
```

The relationship name should end with `__r` for CustomObject.

Comment: I tried using `__r` as well and it didn't work. I have already verified that the name of the `MyCustomObject__r` is correct

Comment: What is the `sfdx` and `cli` version you are using?

Comment: `sfdx-cli/7.94.3-a4e7c7955b`

Comment: Run `sfdx plugins --core`  command to get the sfdx version. I am assuming you do have necessary permission to access the lookup field on Account object.

Comment: that outputs `salesforcedx 51.6.0 (core)` and `sfdx-cli 7.94.3 (core)` and yes I have `modify all` permissions on both objects